# Extracting data from android phone using c#

Tags: c#, android, adb

I am trying to develop a windows form application in `C#`. I have installed managed adb package in `C#` and have started executing the `adb.exe` from `C#` using `madb` but I don't know how to execute `adb pull` command from `C#`. Looking forward to your help.

This is the code I am trying to execute. It runs without any error but no file is being pulled.

```
AndroidDebugBridge mADB;
mADB = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot\adb.exe", true);
mADB.Start();
List<Device> devices = AdbHelper.Instance.GetDevices(AndroidDebugBridge.SocketAddress);
if (devices.Count < 1)
{
  Debug.Fail("Test start-up failed.Please plug in a valid Android device.");
  throw new SystemException("Failed to start Android tests. There are no Android devices connected, please connect a validated Android device.");
}

var TargetName = devices[0].Product;
var TargetSerialNumber = devices[0].SerialNumber;
MessageBox.Show(TargetName, TargetSerialNumber);
var fileToPull = "/data/data/com.whatsapp";
var fls = new FileListingService(devices[0]);
var remoteFileEntry = fls.FindFileEntry(fileToPull);
devices[0].SyncService.PullFile(remoteFileEntry, @"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\a1", new NullSyncProgressMonitor());
```

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of how you are executing adb.exe currently?